# Laravel Many-to-many relationship using pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm creating an application wherein users can be assigned to multiple organisations, and organisations can have many users - many-to-many relationships.

I want to be able to do something like this:
`$user->organisations()->get()` as well as `$organisation->users()->get()`

- I have a `users` table...
- I have an `organisations` table...
- <s>Uh! users-organisations, organisations-users!</s>
- and I have a `user_orgs` pivot/mapping/etc. table

#### Note

The `user_orgs` table has an `org_id` field, and a `user_id` field.

Eloquent assumes and expects `organisation_user` - but that is not what I have named my table, nor do I want to rename.

I set up the following

#### App/Organisation.php

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\User");
}
```

and on user:

#### App/User.php

```
public function organisations(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Organisation");
}
```

And then I test this:

```
Route::get('/test-route', function(){
    $u = App\User::first();
    return $u->organisations()->get();
});
```

and get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.organisation_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `organisations`.*, `organisation_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `organisation_user`.`organisation_id` as `pivot_organisation_id` from `organisations` inner join `organisation_user` on `organisations`.`id` = `organisation_user`.`organisation_id` where `organisation_user`.`user_id` = 1)

The two questions in my mind are, one; how do I specify to Eloquent, to use `user_orgs` instead of assuming `organisation_user`, the same way I can override the `tableName` or `primaryKey` on a model? Two: how can I specify the foreignKey column, such that it uses `user_orgs.org_id` and not `user_orgs.organisation_id`?

But please do suggest alternatives.

Thanks all, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the name of the pivot table by passing it as the second argument to the `belongsToMany()` relationship, like below:

```php
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\User", "user_orgs");
}

public function organisations(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Organisation", "user_orgs");
}
```

Documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

> As mentioned previously, to determine the table name of the relationship's joining table, Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order. However, you are free to override this convention. You may do so by passing a second argument to the belongsToMany method.

Comment: Hey. I thought as much, but the problem is that it then assumes 'organisation_id' and 'user_id', the former of which is aliased 'org_id', any way I can specify that, too?

Comment: Yep: 
> In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing additional arguments to the belongsToMany method. The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to

Comment: It's described in the documentation I linked.

Comment: Funny thing is that I actually read that section twice, prior to posting. Solved now, thanks.